# suid /bin/echo cannot write to elevated files?

Tags: linux

If I copy aside `/bin/echo`, and `chmod u+s`'ing it as root, and then switching back to a weaker user, why can't I run `/root/suidecho "something" > /usr/bin/passwd`? (Permission denied)

Comment: The echo command is not writing the file, the shell is.

Comment: The suggested duplicate answers the question, but I would say only Kusalananda’s Answer spells it out as to *why*

Answer (score 2):

Simply put, because your elevated `echo` is with superlative authority writing to standard output, and then your perfectly normal, non-superuser shell is trying to redirect that to a file to which it does not have write privileges.